# How to use another Observable to control whether code is executed?

Tags: rxjs

I have an Observable and a Subject.

I want to subscribe to Observable(`timer(3000)`) immediately in the code.

If Observable is not completed yet, I will not execute the logic in the Subject pipeline.

```
import { Subject, tap, timer } from 'rxjs'

// I want to subscribe to Observable immediately in the code
timer(3000).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log('success')
})

const s = new Subject<void>()

s.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    console.log('Execute code immediately')
  }),
  tap(() => {
    // Do not execute if timer (3000) not completed
  })
).subscribe()

document.body?.addEventListener('click', () => {
  s.next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine latest will only emit when both observables have emitted a value.

```js
const { fromEvent, timer, combineLatest } = rxjs;

const timer$ = timer(3000);

const click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');

click$.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Clickety click');
});

combineLatest([timer$, click$]).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Both have emitted');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
Click somewhere over here
```